# Apache reverse proxy doesn't work with ports different from 80 and 443

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

When i configure the reverse proxy this way everything works fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName isa.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.178.192:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.178.192:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

but this way with random port in this example 1920 nothing works.

```
<VirtualHost *:1920>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName isa.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.178.192:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.178.192:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Where could the error be? And yes the port 1920 is open in firewall

Comment: What do the logs say? Also the second code snippet you give is exactly the same as the first, it doesn't mention port 1920.

Comment: OK Problem seems to be solved i forgot to edit ports.conf

Comment: distro name that you are using? and check the Listen directive in your apache configuration